# difference between NSUrlConnection and NSMutableUrlConnection

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch

What is the difference between `NSUrlConnection` and `NSMutableUrlConnection`?

Comment: Do you mean NSURLRequest and NSMutableURLRequest?

Comment: One exists and the other doesn't?

Answer (score 7):

As with all `Mutable` classes, `NSMutableURLRequest` can be changed.

If you look at the instance methods in the `NSURLRequest` class reference you see things like **`initWithURL`** and **`initWithURL:cachePolicy:timeoutInterval:`**. You can initialize them, but there are no methods for changing them.

Compare that to the instance methods in the `NSMutableURLRequest` class reference: **`setURL:`** and **`setHTTPMethod`** and such. The mutable version allows you to change things as needed.

Same thing with `NSString` and `NSMutableString`, `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray`, `NSDictionary` and `NSMutableDictionary`: the mutable ones can be changed after initialization.

Comment: In case anyone's wondering, the verb for this is *mutate*. If an object is mutable, you can mutate (change) it. Presumably, this word choice is to clarify that you are changing the object you have and not replacing it with a new one. The opposite is *immutable*: An immutable object, such as an NSURLConnection, NSString, NSArray, or NSDictionary, cannot be mutated once created.